# perl: getting value out of a hash using map

Tags: perl

It seems like I should be able to do this with map, but the actual details elude me.

I have a list of strings in an array, and either zero or one of them may have a hash value.

So instead of doing:

```
foreach $str ( @strings ) {
  $val = $hash{$str} if $hash{$str};
}
```

Can this be replaced with a one-liner using map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it'd be:

```
map { $val = $hash{$_} } @strings;
```

That is, each value of `@strings` is set in `$_` in turn (instead of `$str` as in your foreach).

Of course, this doesn't do much, since you're not doing anything with the value of `$val` in your loop, and we aren't capturing the list returned by `map`.

If you're just trying to generate a list of values, that'd be:

```
 @values = map { $hash{$_} } @strings;
```

But it's more concise to use a hash slice:

```
 @values = @hash{@strings};
```

EDIT:  As pointed out in the comments, if it's possible that `@strings` contains values that aren't keys in your hash, then `@values` will get undefs in those positions.  If that's not what you want, see [Hynek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710557/perl-getting-value-out-of-a-hash-using-map/1711148#1711148) for a solution.

Comment: Hash slice will make array with undefs where string is not presented in hash.

Comment: @Hynek: Good point, +1 on your answer which deals with that situation.

Answer (score 6):

```
@values = grep { $_ } @hash{@strings};
```

to account for the fact that you only want *true* values.

Change this to

```
@values = grep { defined } @hash{@strings};
```

if you want to skip undefined values.

Answer (score 3):

I'm used to do it in this way:

```
@values = map { exists $hash{$_} ? $hash{$_} : () } @strings;
```

but I don't see anything wrong in this way

```
push @values, $hash{$_} for grep exists $hash{$_}, @strings;
```

or

```
@values = @hash{grep exists $hash{$_}, @strings};
```

Comment: +1 However, keep in mind that `@values` may still contain `undef`s. Whether that's desirable depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

```
map { defined $hash{$_} && ( $val =  $hash{$_})} @strings;
```